# jQuery Issue Using .animate Command

Tags: iphone, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

On this page, they give a demo where they have a gray div move across the screen with the click of a button.

Notice that if you click the right button enough times and the DIV block reaches the end of the container it creates horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

I downloaded and modified the code to get rid of the overflow property and what I have so far works BEAUTIFULLY in desktop browsers.

However, Safari on the iPhone handles things a little bit differently. For some reason, Safari completely ignores the overflow property and instead expands the browser window to show you where the block moved to.

I don't want you to be able to see the block. I want it hidden until you hit button again.

Anyone know what the heck is going on?

Here is a pic of the issue:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
div { 
position:absolute; 
background-color:#abc; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;
margin:0px;
max-width:100%;
}

body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
}

* {
overflow:hidden;
clip:rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);  
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="left">&laquo;</button> <button id="right">&raquo;</button>

<div class="block"></div>

<script>
$("#right").click(function(){
$(".block").animate({"left": "+=110%"}, "medium");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
$(".block").animate({"left": "-=110%"}, "medium");
});

</script>
```

Even though I have moved the DIV block off the screen and I have overflow:hidden as a global style, the iPhone will make room for it in the browser window to show you where the DIV has moved to. ANNOYING!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure I understand what you want to accomplish here. But if you want to make the gray box disappear as it leaves towards the end of the document, then I would suggest that you wrap the div inside another div, and set the width of the wrapping element to 100% and overflow: hidden;

Like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Also add the appropriate styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ...
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Note that you need to absolute position the wrapper as well, otherwise the gray block will still be visible outside it. You'll also need to give it some height (I used 100% in my example) or it will be 0px high (due to the absolute positioned child) and nothing will be visible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems like it would make sense and I did try this before. But for the heck of it I tried it again exactly the way you said. But if you wrap the block DIV in a wrapper, it breaks the animation.

When you click on the buttons now, nothing happens....

What do ya think? I am completely lost...

P.S. To clarify, I am looking to slide the entire DIV off the screen and not have it be visible until you click the button again to make it come back. Trying to mimic a transition between two pages similar to what you would see navigating through menus in a native iPhone application.

Comment: I would guess that this is due to the way you move the gray div. The meaning of "110%" changes depending on the parent element. I would use the actual pixel values instead, and fetch the width of the parent in the javascript. Something like: var offset = $('.wrapper').outerWidth(); $('.block').css({left: offset});  (ps, sorry for formatting, cant do line breaks on the ipad :/

Comment: Yah but it still doesn't change the fact that when you wrap the block in a wrapper DIV it breaks the animation functionality....

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to

```
overflow:hidden
HTML:/<div class="clear"></div>
CSS:.clear {clear:both;}
```